# Extract Color from image using OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

Predefined: My A4 sheet will always be of white color.

I need to detect A4 sheet from image. I am able to detect rectangles, now the problem is I am getting multiple rectangles from my image. So I extracted the images from the detected rectangle points.

Now I want to match image color with white color.

Using below method to extract image from contours detected :

```
- (cv::Mat) getPaperAreaFromImage: (std::vector<cv::Point>) square, cv::Mat image
{
    // declare used vars
    int paperWidth  = 210; // in mm, because scale factor is taken into account
    int paperHeight = 297; // in mm, because scale factor is taken into account
    cv::Point2f imageVertices[4];
    float distanceP1P2;
    float distanceP1P3;
    BOOL isLandscape = true;
    int scaleFactor;
    cv::Mat paperImage;
    cv::Mat paperImageCorrected;
    cv::Point2f paperVertices[4];

    // sort square corners for further operations
    square = sortSquarePointsClockwise( square );

    // rearrange to get proper order for getPerspectiveTransform()
    imageVertices[0] = square[0];
    imageVertices[1] = square[1];
    imageVertices[2] = square[3];
    imageVertices[3] = square[2];

    // get distance between corner points for further operations
    distanceP1P2 = distanceBetweenPoints( imageVertices[0], imageVertices[1] );
    distanceP1P3 = distanceBetweenPoints( imageVertices[0], imageVertices[2] );

    // calc paper, paperVertices; take orientation into account
    if ( distanceP1P2 > distanceP1P3 ) {
        scaleFactor =  ceil( lroundf(distanceP1P2/paperHeight) ); // we always want to scale the image down to maintain the best quality possible
        paperImage = cv::Mat( paperWidth*scaleFactor, paperHeight*scaleFactor, CV_8UC3 );
        paperVertices[0] = cv::Point( 0, 0 );
        paperVertices[1] = cv::Point( paperHeight*scaleFactor, 0 );
        paperVertices[2] = cv::Point( 0, paperWidth*scaleFactor );
        paperVertices[3] = cv::Point( paperHeight*scaleFactor, paperWidth*scaleFactor );
    }
    else {
        isLandscape = false;
        scaleFactor =  ceil( lroundf(distanceP1P3/paperHeight) ); // we always want to scale the image down to maintain the best quality possible
        paperImage = cv::Mat( paperHeight*scaleFactor, paperWidth*scaleFactor, CV_8UC3 );
        paperVertices[0] = cv::Point( 0, 0 );
        paperVertices[1] = cv::Point( paperWidth*scaleFactor, 0 );
        paperVertices[2] = cv::Point( 0, paperHeight*scaleFactor );
        paperVertices[3] = cv::Point( paperWidth*scaleFactor, paperHeight*scaleFactor );
    }

    cv::Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform( imageVertices, paperVertices );
    cv::warpPerspective(image, paperImage, warpMatrix, paperImage.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT );

    if (true) {
        cv::Rect rect = boundingRect(cv::Mat(square));
        cv::rectangle(image, rect.tl(), rect.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 5, 8, 0);
        UIImage *object = [self UIImageFromCVMat:paperImage];
    }

    // we want portrait output
    if ( isLandscape ) {
        cv::transpose(paperImage, paperImageCorrected);
        cv::flip(paperImageCorrected, paperImageCorrected, 1);
        return paperImageCorrected;
    }

    return paperImage;
}
```

[image: Demo rectangle]

**EDITED**: I used below method to get the color from image. But now my problem after converting my original image to cv::mat, when I am cropping there is already transparent grey color over my image. So always I am getting the same color.

Is there any direct way to get original color from cv::mat image?

```
- (UIColor *)averageColor: (UIImage *) image {
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char rgba[4];
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

if(rgba[3] > 0) {
    CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
    CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                           green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                            blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                           alpha:alpha];
}
else {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                           green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                            blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                           alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
}
}
```

**EDIT 2** : 
Input Image

[image: Input Image]

Getting this output
[image: Getting this output]

Need to detect only A4 sheet of white color.

Comment: What is the question? You state that you want to match image color to white. Are you asking how to do this? Could you please elaborate on it? Do you mean the average image color, the color of one pixel, the average color within a region of interest, ...?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks.. Yes I have a image of type cv::mat , I need to detect color from it. You can see the a4 sheet in the image added in the question.

Comment: Please attach sample input image, your current output and your expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for a look. Just edited please check.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it using Google Vision api.

My objective was to calculate the cracks for builder purpose from image so in my case User will be using A4 sheet as reference on the image where crack is, and I will capture the A4 sheet and calculate the size taken by each pixel. Then build will tap on two points in the crack, and I will calculate the distance.

In google vision I used document text detection api and printed my app name on A4 sheet fully covered vertically or horizontally. And google vision api detect that text and gives me the coordinate.